# Access Types for Class Types

Tags: c#

When I go to declare a variable of the type Character, with the access type public, it gives me the error, "Unexpected symbol, public".

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    public Character player = new Character();
    Map map = new Map();
    ReciveInput();
}
```

Character Class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace SimpleTextAdventure
{
    public class Character
    {
        public Character ()
        {
            List<string> items = new List<string>();
            public Vector location = new Vector(2,2);
        }
    }
}
```

Removing public fixes the error and then, from what I know, would give it the default type internal which is not what I want. What is the cause of the error?

Comment: Perhaps you should show the whole part of your code where this variable is declared

Comment: My *guess* is that you're declaring a local variable - but it's impossible to say without more context. Not that the code you've shown is syntactically valid anyway on the RHS of the assignment.

Comment: First off, I believe you meant to say _new Character()_

Comment: Where in your code is that line appearing?  Context is everything.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx  <-- I know you're new.  So... get in the habit of checking the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use `public` for fields, not for local variables:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public Character player1 = new Character(); // this will compile

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        public Character player2 = new Character(); // this won't compile
    }
}
```

Removing `public` from `player1` would indeed make it internal. However, the same visibility rules do not apply to local variables defined within a method. They are neither `public` nor `internal`; they are private to that method and only exist whilst the method is being executed, except in the specialist case of closures.

On the assumption that you want to make `player` available to other parts of your code, what you need to do is remove the declaration from `Main` and instead, add the following to its class:

```
public static Character player = new Character();
```

Please note though that such global variables are very bad practice. You are far better off creating it in `Main` then passing it out to other classes as you create them via their constructors. For example, if `Map` needs to know about the character's location and so needs access to `player`, you might change your code to:

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Character player = new Character();
    Map map = new Map(player);
    ReciveInput();
}

public class Map
{
    private readonly Character _player;

    public Map(Character player)
    {
        _player = player;
    }

    public SomeMethod
    {
        // access the character using _player here
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what the purpose of constructors is then. A class's variables are declared outside of the constructor and then the constructor receives parameters and can then act on them? And if a non public variable is declared inside a function it is considered local and only exists inside of that function?

Comment: @j76goatboy, ah, by the sounds of it you need to start at the beginning and learn the basics of C#. specifically around classes, objects, fields and constructors. All will then make sense :)

Comment: I come from Lua and, for the last couple days, have been working to clear the fog surrounding C#. So the purpose of a constructor is to accept parameters for that class instance?